# Reference jquery appended element after creation by name?

Tags: jquery, object, dom

I'm creating a few jQuery objects that reference elements and appending them to the DOM. I would like to be able to reference them by name so that I don't have to use a bunch of selectors to tie events to them. Here is a dumbed down example 
of the code:

```
<div class="body>

</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        wrapper = $("<div />")
            .addClass("wrapper")
            .click(function(e){
                if (e.target === this)
                    $(this).hide();
            })
            $('.body').wrap(wrapper);

        close = $("<button />")
            .addClass("close")
            .text('CLICK TO CLOSE')
            .click(function(e){
                 ///HIDE ".wrapper" FROM HERE
                 $(wrapper).hide();
                 ///HIDE ".wrapper" FROM HERE
            })
            .prependTo($('.body'));
})
```

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwm6qjhj/)

I want to be able to click on the "close" button and hide "wrapper". I could hide it using `$('.wrapper').hide()` but there are going to be multiple wrappers, it needs to target just the one. I could use `$(this).closest('.wrapper').hide()` but now it's getting messy. Is there a way to reference the "wrapper" variable from within "close" to avoid all of the extra code?

Comment: What is the desired structure? Is `.wrapper` the outer-most container? Does each `.wrapper` element contain its own `.body`? Is `.close` a child or sibling of `.body`?

Comment: Yeah for the dom structure .wrapper is outer then .body then inside body is .close (they're modals in the end this is just the simple version). In the code instead of in the DOM ready this is called in a init function so the code is called once per "modal", but I figured if I could solve it for one I could apply it to all. Will update though if you think it is all necessaary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue wasn't with the scope of the click function, it was how the wrap() function worked. When you use jQuery .Wrap() it wraps a copy of the structure around the specified elements and returns the original as a set, which in my case was losing it's reference. So instead of wrapping the .body I simply appended the wrapper where the body was using '.replaceWith' and appended the body to that (essentially .wrap() but in my own way). This worked and allowed me to hide the wrapper using just

```
wrapper.hide()
```

Very clean.

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $body = $('.body');
        wrapper = $("<div />")
                .addClass("wrapper")
                .click(function(e){
                    if (e.target === this)
                        $(this).hide();
                })
                $body.replaceWith(wrapper)
                wrapper.append($body);

        close = $("<button />")
                .addClass("close")
                .text('CLICK TO CLOSE')
                .click(function(e){
                     wrapper.hide();
                })
                .prependTo($('.body'));
})
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1s9o198a/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you create a variable for the wrapper, it's still a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). So do your wrap at the same time as the assignment, where it actually becomes something in the DOM, and it can be hidden.

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zkegxyco/) fiddle.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var wrapper = $(".body").wrap($("<div></div>")
            .addClass("wrapper")
            .click(function (e) {
                if (e.target === this) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }));

        $("<button></button>")
            .addClass("close")
            .text("CLICK TO CLOSE")
            .click(function () {
                $(wrapper.parent(".wrapper")).hide();
            })
            .prependTo($(".body"));
    });
}(jQuery));
```

This version of your script passes [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) with the exception of allowing `this`.

Comment: That is much closer and I appreciate it but I may have worded one thing poorly, I need the close button to hide the black wrapper (and thus everything in it) not just the red ".body". Sorry for the confusion, but great help

Comment: That one is certainly possible, it works, it just one that I consider more messy. But if no one has a better solution that may be it.

Comment: I don't see any easier way myself, signing off for the evening. (I also don't see what is wrong with it personally.) Good luck!

Comment: @DasBeasto pretty stubborn on giving rep and accepting an answer then eh?! Sheesh

Comment: Yes, I am fairly stubborn when it comes to code that I will implement in my projects. I am still hoping for a cleaner solution. After accepting an answer people are less inclined to provide alternatives. Couple that with the fact that I just got back from vacation...

Comment: That's all well and good but if something helps... even only a little... I still up-vote. And sure, aren't we all the same when trying to get the most elegant solution. But if you're looking for some ultra concise method call, you're using the wrong site. You should be asking on code-review or something..